# Update firebase from arraylist using angular

Tags: angular, firebase, arraylist

I have array list of items containing key and some Jason data . I want to update the firebase data from this list . When using foreach take a long time
here the code :
serveries :

```
updateSuspenseCode(codeID: string, suspenseCodes) {

    return this.db.object('/suspense/' + codeID).update(suspenseCodes);

  }
```

the list which I want to update the firebase from it  . it is contain 1000 value

```
 this.listDocketUpdate.forEach(x => {

        this.dbServ.updateSuspenseCode(x.key, {
          name: x.name,
          glid: x.glid,
          accName: x.accName,
          comment: x.comment + " updated in: " + this.dateToday2
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make a firebase call for each in your list. if these lists are large, you should consider batching them if it's with firestore.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

```js
MyList.forEach(item => firebaseApp.firestore().collection("location").add(item));
```

Comment: Can you clarify more

Comment: there isn't much information to go on, I suggest looking at the documentation I linked and getting familiar with it

Comment: I have used this code but not working 'list.forEach(item=>firebase.firestore().collection("my database name").doc("suspense").update(item.key,{item}))'

Comment: MyList.forEach(item => firebaseApp.firestore().collection("location").add(item));      //how to use the update method instead of add

Comment: you will need logic to know what document it is to update so you can update `"location/" + document_id)`